# Using search to find the deepest node in a tree and then moving it

Tags: tree, lisp, common-lisp, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

i have a tree and i want to find the longest path to the deepest node and then i want to change it somehow to make it more balanced. In this very simple example i want to move 4 since it is the deepest path and instead put it in 1 so that the difference in height is not as big. I want to do this in lisp and I'm not quite sure how, i know i want to use a search but its having it so that it actually does find the longest. I know how to get the path from the root to a given node but I'm not sure how to actually get the deepest node. I think i have an idea in my head of how i could put the deepest node onto a better part but any advice would be great.

So far I've only got some code that will return the depth of the tree, but it there any way that i could get it to return what is the deepest node(s)?

```
(defun maxdepth (l)
  (cond ((null l) 0)
    ((atom l) 0)
    (t (+ 1 (max (maxdepth (cadr l)) (maxdepth (caddr l)))))))
```

[image: Basically in this very simple example i want to move 4 since it is the deepest path and instead put it in 1 so that the difference in height is not as big]

[image]

Comment: what code dio you have so far?

Comment: I don't actually know where to start, i've got code that will find the height of the tree but i don't know whether that it actually relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume based on your implementation of `maxdepth` that your tree is of the format `(value left-branch &optional right-branch)` if a node has branches, or just `value` if it's a leaf node.

Because not doing so results in a pathological case where we have to rebuild the entire tree with every iteration, `(value)` is also a leaf node, as is `(value nil)` and `(value nil nil)`.

I'm also assuming you want to move the branches within the existing tree instead of creating a new tree with the branch in a different place.

If so, your goal is to preserve the last non-leaf node you encountered when calculating the `maxdepth` of your tree.

The new function will work exactly like `maxdepth`, except it'll return three values instead of one. In the case of your graph, represented as `(1 (2 (3 4)))`, it would return:

```
3
(3 4)
LEFT
```

...where 3 is the depth, (3 4) is the deepest non-leaf node, and LEFT
means that the 4 was on the left branch (`CADR`) of that node and not the
right (`CADDR`) branch.

That means every time it uses its own return value, it must capture all three return values so it can re-return them, and special treatment is required
to make sure that we don't get "4" as a return value, which you wouldn't
be able to move.

Because we're tossing 3 values around, we have to define our own versions of `max` and `1+` as macros (`l` and `betterp` are free variables below. Their values are the `l` argument to `maxdepth` and the comparison operator to use, respectively):

```
(defmacro my-max (value-form1 value-form2)
  (let ((n1 (gensym))
    (v1 (gensym))
    (n2 (gensym))
    (v2 (gensym))
    (pos1 (gensym))
    (pos2 (gensym)))
    `(multiple-value-bind (,n1 ,v1 ,pos1) ,value-form1
       (multiple-value-bind (,n2 ,v2 ,pos2) ,value-form2
     (if (funcall betterp ,n1 ,n2)
         (apply #'values (cons ,n1 (if (consp ,v1)
                                       (list ,v1 ,pos1)
                                       (list l 'left))))
         (apply #'values (cons ,n2 (if (consp ,v2)
                                       (list ,v2 ,pos2)
                                       (list l 'right)))))))))

(defmacro my-1+ (value-form)
  (let ((number (gensym))
    (value (gensym))
    (position (gensym)))
    `(multiple-value-bind (,number ,value ,position) ,value-form
       (values (1+ ,number) ,value ,position))))
```

Because a leaf node can be either a naked value or a list with one
non-null member, we need some functions to help smooth those differences
out. The first function recognizes a leaf, and the second converts any leaf into a bare value:

```
(defun leafp (val)
  (or (not (listp val))
      (= (length (remove nil val)) 1)))

(defun leaf-value (leaf)
  (if (listp leaf)
      (car leaf)
      leaf))
```

Then it's on to the `maxdepth` function itself, which I've only made small changes to:

```
(defun maxdepth (l &optional (betterp #'>=))
  (cond ((null l) (values -1 l nil))
        ((leafp l) (values 0 (leaf-value l) nil))
        (t (my-1+ (my-max (maxdepth (cadr l) betterp) (maxdepth (caddr l) betterp))))))
```

The biggest change is that `maxdepth` can be turned into `mindepth` by passing `#'<=` as the `betterp` argument. This is because we have to locate the place on the tree that the deep value we find is going to.

Also, `l` = `NIL` is treated as having a depth of -1. This is so that if you have the branch `(8 NIL 10)`, the deepest value will be the 10 on the `RIGHT` and not the `NIL, which presumably is not a node at all, just a stub from where a node was removed or not added yet.

*Moving* the node, once found, can be done by using `(setf (cdr x))` or `(setf (cddr x))`. But first, you need to write a `mindepth` function:

```
(defun mindepth (tree)
    (maxdepth tree #'<=))
```

I came up with this function to actually move the value from the deepest node to the shallowest:

```
(defun balance-tree (l)
  (multiple-value-bind (deepest-depth deepest-node deepest-side)
      (maxdepth l)
    (multiple-value-bind (shallowest-depth shallowest-node shallowest-side)
         (mindepth l)
      (let ((max-value (case deepest-side
                        ((left) (prog1
                                    (cadr deepest-node)
                                 (setf (cadr deepest-node) nil)))
                        ((right) (prog1
                                    (caddr deepest-node)
                                   (setf (cddr deepest-node) nil))))))
         (case shallowest-side
          ((left) (cond ((= (length shallowest-node) 1)
                         (setf (cdr shallowest-node) (list max-value)))
                        ((leafp (cadr shallowest-node))
                         (setf (cadr shallowest-node)
                         (list (leaf-value (cadr shallowest-node)) max-value)))
                        (t (setf (cadr shallowest-node) max-value))))
          ((right) (case (length shallowest-node)
                      ((1) (setf (cdr shallowest-node)
                                 (list nil max-value)))
                      ((2) (setf (cddr shallowest-node)
                                 (list max-value)))
                      ((3) (cond ((null (caddr shallowest-node))
                                  (setf (caddr shallowest-node)
                                        max-value))
                                 ((leafp (caddr shallowest-node))
                                  (setf (caddr shallowest-node)
                                        (list (leaf-value (caddr shallowest-node))
                                              max-value)))
                                 (t (error "Didn't think this was reachable!"))))))))))
         ;; Return value: the modified tree.
         l)
```

If you call this function repeatedly on the tree I used in testing, which is `(1 (2 (3 4)) (5 (6 (7 (8 nil 10)))))`, eventually
the tree alternates between the following two states:

```
(1 (2 (3 4) 10) (5 (6 (7 NIL)) (8 NIL)))
(1 (2 (3 NIL 4) 10) (5 (6 (7 NIL)) (8 NIL)))
```

...which both have a `maxdepth` of 3.

When used on your original example, it produces the correct result:

```
CL-USER> (balance-tree '(1 (2 (3 4))))
(1 (2 (3 NIL)) 4)
```

...which is equivalent to:

```
(1 (2 3) 4)
```

If you want to convert instances like `(3 NIL)` into plain `3`, there is a
function for that, but it walks the entire tree and rebuilds it, so use sparingly:

```
(defun clean-tree (tree)
  (cond
    ((null tree) nil)
    ((atom tree) tree)
    ((= (length (remove nil tree)) 1)
     (car tree))
    ((and (= (length tree) 3)
          (null (caddr tree)))
     (setf (cddr tree) nil)
     (clean-tree tree))
    (t
     (unless (null (cadr tree))
       (setf (cadr tree)
             (clean-tree (cadr tree))))
     (unless (null (caddr tree))
       (setf (caddr tree)
             (clean-tree (caddr tree))))
       tree)))
```

Because of those two cases where it simply returns its argument or a function of its argument, `clean-tree` should always be used in a `setf` form:

```
(setf tree (clean-tree tree))
```

Here's `clean-tree`'s output for one of the example outputs above:

```
CL-USER> (clean-tree '(1 (2 (3 4) 10) (5 (6 (7 NIL)) (8 NIL))))
(1 (2 (3 4) 10) (5 (6 7) 8))
```

Comment: Can't believe I'm only seeing this now, what an amazing answer! Thanks so much for it, I had fixed it before you posted this answer but my solution pales in comparison! Definitely be keeping an eye on this as it was really useful just reading i even though i haven't looked at the problem in a good few months. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use depth first search, increment a counter each time (per node) you expand a node, keep a list of all the nodes explored, and then parse it to find the highest counter which should be the deepest path.

Comment: Just wondering how you could get it to go for the highest counter? That's what i couldn't get my head around as i thought depth first would just go to the shortest?

Comment: In the goal checking function you can make it so that the goal is that there are no node remaining in your "fringe"

Comment: Is there any chance you could give me an example or something similar? I just can't imagine how you would apply that to the other DFS functions I've seen!